# Using Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location in external DLL always returns an empty string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I am trying to save a simple config file to the same directory as the application. My program has 2 "layers," the application and the engine. The engine is compiled as a DLL and used as a dependency for the application. Saving the config is the job of the engine, so I made a config manager class with the following property.

```
public static class ConfigManager
{
    static string ConfigPath { get { return Path.Combine(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "\\settings.cfg"); } }
}
```

However, this always returns an empty string. When called from the main application it successfully gets the path. I've also tried multiple different alternatives I found online, with the same result. These include the following:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
AppContext.BaseDirectory
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

I know that `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` works fine because I use it in my engine's logger to determine where the log call is coming from. I even tested it with `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location` and that actually does work. If anybody can give me some insight as to what is happening that would be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I would implement a public interface in the DLL (e. g. as singleton) - the DLL should not read its configuration (perhaps have an inbuilt default configuration).  E. g. in the application you open a config file (with means of Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location or other) as a stream and tell the DLL, from which stream it can read the configuration. Like that the DLL stays testable and flexible.

Comment: The location of the loaded file that contains the manifest. If the assembly is loaded from a byte array, such as when using Load(Byte[]), the value returned is an empty string (""). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=net-7.0

Comment: What is loading your DLL?

Comment: @Steve another application that I wrote is using it as an assembly

Comment: Yeah, but does this other application load the DLL the "normal" way, or could it be using a framework that's doing something weird? If you haven't, I'd make the simplest little console application that uses your library, and make the call, see if it works.